# Download and open word file in Angular

Tags: angular, download, blob

I receive a word file from server, which is supposed to be downloaded (and opened automatically) on the client:

**DocomentComponent:**

```
@Input() public fileName: string;
    
     public saveFinalReport() {
      this.getFinalReportSubscription = this.documentService.getFinalReport(caseId)
        .subscribe((res) => {
          FileSaver.saveAs(res, `${this.fileName}.doc`);
          // code for opening the downloaded file
        });
    }
```

My qiuestion is how to open the downloaded file prgramatically.

I have even tried this:

```
  private openFile(data: File) {
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(url);
  }
```

But is not helpful. Plus, it is a requirement that file be save with `fileName`. There is however no requirement that the user be prevented from renaming the downloaded file.

Comment: AFAIK neither requirement is possible, i.e. you can't force a file to open, nor can you force it to be saved with a particular name, as these would both be MASSIVE security flaws.

Comment: I have already succeeded saving the file with a custom (particular) name. So this condition is possible to fulfill. 
Also, I  have looked at several examples where people asked how to open a filed retrieved from server.; and they got answer like using window.open(url) [which is not working for me though!]. So I don't think this is impossible either.

Comment: You got it so that the user could not change the filename?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: It's of course possible to set a default filename, but as far as I know you can't prevent the user from changing it.

Comment: I never said I don't want to prevent the user from changing file name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242816/discussion-between-will-alexander-and-alpha-bravo-charlie).